# Use Git on a shared drive within WSL

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, network-drive

I have a network-attached drive, `T:` that I can access via Windows File Explorer or GitBash just fine. But in WSL, I cannot use git to push to a remote located on the drive. Here is my workflow:

Mount the remote drive

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/t
sudo mount -t drvfs T: /mnt/t -o uid=kkovacs -o gid=kkovacs
```

Create the remote repo

```
cd /mnt/t/MyFolder
mkdir remote_repo
cd remote_repo
git init --bare
```

Create the local repo and add the remote

```
cd ~
mkdir local_repo
cd local_repo
git init
git remote add origin /mnt/t/MyFolder/remote_repo
```

Add a new file to the local repo, commit it, and try to push

```
touch asdf
git add asdf
git commit -m "added asdf"
git push origin master
```

The output of the push command is this:

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 6.72 KiB | 573.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database /mnt/t/MyFolder/remote_repo/./objects/incoming-p5fut6
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: remote unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To /mnt/t/MyFolder/remote_repo/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '/mnt/t/MyFolder/remote_repo/'
```

I have also checked using `ls -l` that I am the owner of all the files everywhere. This all works just fine with GitBash, but I want to use WSL.

**EDIT**: I posted a [new question](https://superuser.com/questions/1532034/shared-drive-permissions-from-wsl) about a slightly different but very similar topic.

Comment: I could never get that to work, here are some others [unpack failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362918/git-push-error-unpack-failed-index-pack-abnormal-exit)

Comment: Unfortunately, those solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Edited

Recent days I found if i plug my portable drive in after launching wsl, there won't be accessible in wsl. I tried `wsl -t <distro_name>` and log-in wsl again to mount it successfully.

Here's my original answer.

In my case, it is caused by a file system error. Though I have know idea about how such a file system error come into being, I managed to fix it with `chkdsk.exe`. Say we are fixing the drive with volume label as `g:\`, then following command could be used.

```
chkdsk.exe g: /F
```

May this help you :)